# Par bonheur, par chance, heureusement

Tags: sens, vocabulaire, usage, synonymes

What are the differences, if any, between "par bonheur", "par chance" et "heureusement" ?
According to my dictionary, they all convey " fortunately; luckily; thankfully;".

Comment: What are the differences, if any, between "fortunately", "luckily" and "thankfully"? They are all synonyms, thus, you may use them interchangeably unless you mean something specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The meaning is the almost the same.

**Par bonheur** and **Par chance** are totally interchangeable, though **Par bonheur** is less frequent.

**Heureusement** can be used a way the two other don't :

- Expressing relief (soulagement) rather than just luck or an unexpected positive event :

> Tu as fini par arriver, heureusement sinon j'aurais été obligé de partir!

- Contruction with "que"

> Heureusement que tu es venu, je ne connaissais personne avant que tu arrives!